# If $a^2$% of $b$ is equal to $b^3$% of $c$ and $c^4$ % of $a$ is equal to $b$ % of $b$, then what is the relation between $a$ and $b?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

If $a^2$% of $b$ is equal to $b^3$% of $c$ and $c^4$ % of $a$ is equal to $b$ % of $b$, then what is the relation between $a$ and $b?$

According to my way of doing it: $a^2b = b^3c = c^4a = b^2$

Equating $a^2b=b^2$ I got $a^2=b$. But the correct answer is $a^9=b^{10}$. How?

Answer (score 3):

From the hypotheses you have:

$$\frac{a^2}{100}\cdot b=\frac{b^3}{100}\cdot c\\
\frac{c^4}{100}\cdot a=\frac{b}{100}\cdot b$$

Or, simplifying:

$$a^2b=b^3c\\
c^4a=b^2$$

Notice that you do **not** have equality between the upper and lower expressions (from the hypotheses). Using the upper equality, you get that $c=a^2/b^2$; and substituting this into the lower equality yields

$$\frac{a^8}{b^8}\cdot a=b^2\implies a^9=b^{10}$$

as desired.